# DOMDocument::loadXML() error

Tags: domdocument, php

When I use DOMDocument in PHP file, I get the following errors:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag nodes line 7 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag node line 6 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag field line 5 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag field line 5 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag field line 4 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag field line 4 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag node line 3 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag node line 2 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag node line 2 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag nodes line 1 in Entity, line: 7 in D:\wamp\www\dom1.php on line 77
>   array(0) { }

**The php code is as follows:**

```
<?php
class MyDOMDocument extends DOMDocument
{
    public function toArray(DOMNode $oDomNode = null)
    {
        // return empty array if dom is blank
        if (is_null($oDomNode) && !$this->hasChildNodes()) {
            return array();
        }
        $oDomNode = (is_null($oDomNode)) ? $this->documentElement : $oDomNode;
        if (!$oDomNode->hasChildNodes()) {
            $mResult = $oDomNode->nodeValue;
        } else {
            $mResult = array();
            foreach ($oDomNode->childNodes as $oChildNode) {
                // how many of these child nodes do we have?
                // this will give us a clue as to what the result structure should be
                $oChildNodeList = $oDomNode->getElementsByTagName($oChildNode->nodeName); 
                $iChildCount = 0;
                // there are x number of childs in this node that have the same tag name
                // however, we are only interested in the # of siblings with the same tag name
                foreach ($oChildNodeList as $oNode) {
                    if ($oNode->parentNode->isSameNode($oChildNode->parentNode)) {
                        $iChildCount++;
                    }
                }
                $mValue = $this->toArray($oChildNode);
                $sKey   = ($oChildNode->nodeName{0} == '#') ? 0 : $oChildNode->nodeName;
                $mValue = is_array($mValue) ? $mValue[$oChildNode->nodeName] : $mValue;
                // how many of thse child nodes do we have?
                if ($iChildCount > 1) {  // more than 1 child - make numeric array
                    $mResult[$sKey][] = $mValue;
                } else {
                    $mResult[$sKey] = $mValue;
                }
            }
            // if the child is <foo>bar</foo>, the result will be array(bar)
            // make the result just 'bar'
            if (count($mResult) == 1 && isset($mResult[0]) && !is_array($mResult[0])) {
                $mResult = $mResult[0];
            }
        }
        // get our attributes if we have any
        $arAttributes = array();
        if ($oDomNode->hasAttributes()) {
            foreach ($oDomNode->attributes as $sAttrName=>$oAttrNode) {
                // retain namespace prefixes
                $arAttributes["@{$oAttrNode->nodeName}"] = $oAttrNode->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        // check for namespace attribute - Namespaces will not show up in the attributes list
        if ($oDomNode instanceof DOMElement && $oDomNode->getAttribute('xmlns')) {
            $arAttributes["@xmlns"] = $oDomNode->getAttribute('xmlns');
        }
        if (count($arAttributes)) {
            if (!is_array($mResult)) {
                $mResult = (trim($mResult)) ? array($mResult) : array();
            }
            $mResult = array_merge($mResult, $arAttributes);
        }
        $arResult = array($oDomNode->nodeName=>$mResult);
        return $arResult;
    }
}

$sXml = <<<XML
<nodes>
    <node>text<node>
    <node>
        <field>hello<field>
        <field>world<field>
    <node>
<nodes>
XML;

$dom = new MyDOMDocument;
$dom -> loadXml($sXml);
var_dump($dom->toArray());
?>
```

source location:
http://bd.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the `elements` e.g. `</node>` and `</field>`

```
<nodes>
    <node>text<node>
<node>
    <field>hello<field>
    <field>world<field>
<node>
<nodes>
```

Change to:

```
<nodes>
    <node>text</node>
<node>
    <field>hello</field>
    <field>world</field>
</node>
</nodes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your XML into:

```
$sXml = <<<XML
<nodes>
    <node>text</node>
    <node>
        <field>hello</field>
        <field>world</field>
    </node>
</nodes>
XML;
```

Notice the pair `<nodes></nodes>`, `<node></node>`, `<field></field>`. You have to match every opened tag with it's closed tag. [See w3Schools for more about XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp).